# How to optimize images for e-readers?

Tags: ebook

I am preparing a PDF for use on black-and-white e-readers. Most of the pages will contain illustrations. I noticed that, on black-and-write e-readers, the graphics do not look very good, so perhaps I do not need to put high-quality graphics into the file prior to exporting the PDF.

Is there any method for optimally preparing the images so that they look good on an e-reader, but do not require any unnecessary file size or load time?

Comment: Not all e-readers are equal: screen measurements, display technology, image resampling algorithm. "One" solution to cater for all, most, or even a reasonable subset is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Images should save as JPG files. 
In adobe photoshop press CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S.
Then new window will pop up.
You can reduce the quality, this will reduce size (But keep it clear to read)
Use resolutions to 72pixels/inch
Then save.

Comment: I know I can reduce the quality. Is there any optimal way to reduce the quality and perhaps even apply image effects so the resulting graphic looks identical to when one views the original graphic, but now loads faster?

Comment: @Village: yes, and it's called "JPEG"...